# Extract list of objects from another Python list based on attribute

Tags: python

I have a Python list filled with instances of a class I defined.

I would like to create a new list with all the instances from the original list that meet a certain criterion in one of their attributes.

That is, for all the elements in `list1`, filled with instances of some `class obj`, I want all the elements for which `obj.attrib == someValue`.

I've done this using just a normal for loop, looping through and checking each object, but my list is extremely long and I was wondering if there was a faster/more concise way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's definitely a more concise way to do it, with a list comprehension:

```
filtered_list = [obj for obj in list1 if obj.attrib==someValue]
```

I don't know if you can go any faster though, because in the problem as you described you'll always have to check every object in the list somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use pandas series. Read your list into a pandas series `your_list`.
Then you can filter by using the `[]` syntax and the `.apply` method:

```
def check_attrib(obj, value):
    return obj.attrib==value

new_list = your_list[your_list.apply(check_attrib)]
```

Remember the `[]` syntax filters a series by the boolean values of the series inside the brackets. For example:

```
spam = [1, 5, 3, 7]
eggs = [True, True, False, False]
```

Than `spam[eggs]` returns:

`[1, 5]`

This is a vector operation and in general should be more efficient than a loop.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you could also use [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=filter%20built#filter) and a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
filtered_lst1 = filter(lambda obj: obj.attrib==someValue, lst1)
```