# taking specific elements from a DF and putting them into own DF. Python

Tags: python, dataframe

Can someone tell me what function would tell me the number of times each string value is iterated through a Dataframe column. I tried using count but that is only returning a 1 each time the value is iterated through. An example of what I would be iterating through is below. Much obliged...

```
dataframe_s = dataframe['status']
print (dataframe_s)
results:
1. extinct
2. extant
3. extant
4. extant
5. extinct
```

Comment: Do you need to reset in the indexing? Because you can simply select from your original dataframe using the bracket syntax and assign that to a new variable name. Would that serve your purpose? Here is how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443447/extract-list-of-objects-from-another-python-list-based-on-attribute/37444343#37444343

Comment: Now I'm just trying to figure out how to find the number of times a certain string value is called. (how many times is extant called in column)

Comment: For that, the groupby and count approach should work, as chas suggested. I suggest you mark his answer as "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, we're talking about a pandas-dataframe here. So `count()`in combination with`groupby()` would do the Job:

```
print(dataframe)

     animal   status
0  dinosaur  extinct
1       dog   extant
2       cat   extant
3     horse   extant
4      dodo  extinct

print(dataframe.groupby(["status"])["status"].count())

status
extant     3
extinct    2
Name: status, dtype: int64
```

If you need more details, check the [groupby-Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)