# Append name of dataframes to list python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 10 dataframes (ex: dfc,df1,df2,df3,df4,dft1,dft2,dft3,dft4,dft5). I want to check the length of each dataframe. If the length of dataframe is less than 2, I want to add the name of that dataframe to an empty list. How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest using a dictionary, to store the dataframes, with their names as keys.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [taking specific elements from a DF and putting them into own DF. Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724469/taking-specific-elements-from-a-df-and-putting-them-into-own-df-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the dataframes in a dictionary using their names as keys and then iterate over the dictionary:

```py
dic = {'df1': df1,'df2': df2,'df3': df3,'df4': df4}
d = []
for k, v in dic.items():
    if len(v) < 2:
        d.append(k)
print(d)
```

You can also use aa list comprehension instead of the for loop:

```py
dic = {'df1': df1,'df2': df2,'df3': df3,'df4': df4}
d = [k for k, v in dic.items() if len(v) < 2]
```

Comment: Yes first you need to build the dataframes

Comment: oh sorry i was trying to execute it inside another condition.. my bad.. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to create a list of the short dataframe-list.
I would do it like this:

```
dataframes = ['d','df1','df2','df3','df4','dft1','dft2','dft3','dft4','dft5']

short_dataframe = [] # the empy list.
for frame in dataframes:
    if len(frame) < 2:
        short_dataframe.append(frame) # adds the frame to the empty list

print(short_dataframe)
```

result of the print = ['d']